# Расчет манхэттенское расстояние используя Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Подскажите, как можно модифицировать код, для расчета манхэттенского расстояния, что бы избавиться от цикла то есть использовать для расчета только библиотеку Numpy.

```
import numpy as np

train = np.random.randint(0, 255, (1000, 10))
test = np.random.randint(0, 255, (100, 10))

num_train = train.shape[0]
num_test = test.shape[0]

dists = np.zeros((num_test, num_train), np.float32)
for i_test in range(num_test):
    dists[i_test] = np.linalg.norm(test[i_test] - train, ord=1, axis=1)
```

Comment: Вы хотит получить расстояния для прямого произведения `train` на `test`?

Comment: Расчет расстояния между двумя точками вычисляется по такой формуле(это я для примера): (p1, p2) и (q1, q2) равно |p1 - q1| + |p2 - q2|

Comment: В итоге должна получиться матрица с размерностью 100*1000 по которой можно увидеть изменение расстояния между точками train и test. Я пытаюсь этим сделать свой алгоритм KNearestNeighbors

Comment: Ок, это и есть прямое (декартово) произведение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что вам нужно - вычислить декартово произведение `train` и `test`, получить разности в виде векторов, перевести разницы в расстояния. Небольшое демо:

```
train = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]])
test  = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2]])

# train = [[1 1] [2 2] [3 3]]
# test = [[1 1] [2 2]]

a = np.repeat(train[np.newaxis, :, :], test.shape[0], axis=0)
# каждая строка нового массива - копия train
# a = [
#     [[1 1] [2 2] [3 3]]
#     [[1 1] [2 2] [3 3]]
# ]

b = np.repeat(test[:, np.newaxis, :], train.shape[0], axis=1)
# каждый столбец нового массива - копия test
# b = [
#     [[1 1] [1 1] [1 1]]
#     [[2 2] [2 2] [2 2]]
# ]

c = a - b
# попарные разницы векторов из train и test
# c = [
#     [[ 0  0] [ 1  1] [ 2  2]]
#     [[-1 -1] [ 0  0] [ 1  1]]
# ]

dists = np.linalg.norm(с, axis=2, ord=1)
# заменяем разницы на манхэтенновские нормы
# dists = [
#     [0. 2. 4.]
#     [2. 0. 2.]
# ]
```

Рабочий пример:

```
import numpy as np

train = np.random.randint(0, 255, (1000, 10))
test  = np.random.randint(0, 255, (100, 10))

a = np.repeat(train[np.newaxis, :         , :], test .shape[0], axis=0)
b = np.repeat(test [:         , np.newaxis, :], train.shape[0], axis=1)

dists = np.linalg.norm(a - b, axis=2, ord=1)

print(dists.shape)
print(dists)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за такой подробный ответ)